# Extra Space in GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I am trying to remove the extra space that shows among the images in a gridview.

[image]

My XML file has the following format:

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gallery_grid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Note: I tried changing the value in the `horizontalSpacing` attribute but that does not seem to do anything. I want the images to be shown in 2 columns when in portrait mode and 3 columns when in landscape mode. What I do not want is the wasted space among the images. I would like to have them stretched and remove the wasted space.

Comment: increase the width of your items in the gridview

Comment: Have you created layout for landscape also?

Comment: can you put your griditem layout file?

Comment: Try to set GridView width "wrap_content".

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gallery_grid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
</FrameLayout>
```

You asking the system to fill all the screen with 2 columns, so I think he override the attribute `android:horizontalSpacing`.

Answer (score 0):

This is where the magic happens:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
```

In the `getView()` method of your `GridView` adapter. Increase the values (width, heigth) to suite your requirements

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gallery_grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />
```